# Invalid syntax issue with mongodb update query

Tags: python, mongodb, visual-studio-code

I am using mongoDB as my project's database. Project is written in python and I am using the pymongo library. I am attempting to update certain fields in my documents, but keep getting the "invalid syntax error". To make it stranger, I can get the same query to run fine in mongo shell. However, the same line of code in my .py file throws the invalid error.

Tried other queries, e.f. find() and generic update (not using the $set operator), and those work fine.

The following piece of code throws the invalid syntax error in VS code. However, this same exact code runs fine in mongo shell.

`db.fearlessData.update({"Country":"Canada"},{$set: {"Type":"Canadian_Wedding_2"}}, {multi:true})`

---- when I run in mongo shell:

```
> db.fearlessData.update({"Country":"Canada"},{$set: {"Type":"Canadian_Wedding_2"}}, {multi:true})

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 10, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

----The general update query also runs fine in the .py file (no syntax error)

```
db.fearlessData.update({"Name":"Test_Elena2"},{"Name":"Test_Elena_3"})
```

Expect the code to run without any syntax error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJL11.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double quotes to options:

```
> db.fearlessData.update({"Country":"Canada"},{"$set": {"Type":"Canadian_Wedding_2"}}, {"multi":true})
```